# Spring Security "requiresSecure()" results ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have the following http security configuration

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
        .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/login?authorization_error=true")
        .and()
    .csrf()
        .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize")).disable()
    .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        .logoutUrl("/logout.do")
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .usernameParameter("j_username")
        .passwordParameter("j_password")
        .failureUrl("/login?authentication_error=true")
        .loginPage("/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do")
        .and()
    .requiresChannel()
         .anyRequest().requiresSecure();
```

This results with **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** when I try to access *https://{url}/login*. However, when I remove `requiresSecure()` as the following I can access *https://{url}/login*

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
        .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/login?authorization_error=true")
        .and()
    .csrf()
        .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize")).disable()
    .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        .logoutUrl("/logout.do")
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .usernameParameter("j_username")
        .passwordParameter("j_password")
        .failureUrl("/login?authentication_error=true")
        .loginPage("/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do")
        .and()
    .requiresChannel().anyRequest();
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: This did not get solved?

Comment: also check that you are not on a server that works in unsecured mode, and a load balancer does SSL offloading - in these scenarios if you do requiresSecure() you might get endless redirects

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it might be because of the order of your blocks of code. Please try the following code and see if it works. Adding all the antMatchers to the same code block can be the trick.

```
http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/login?authorization_error=true")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .logoutUrl("/logout.do")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .failureUrl("/login?authentication_error=true")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do")
                .and()
            .requiresChannel()
                .anyRequest().requiresSecure()
                .and()                
            .csrf()
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize")).disable();
```